# How to properly implement the BNF grammar described in the Lua manual?

Tags: lua, bnf

This is a portion of the BNF grammar for Lua described in the [Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html) section 8:

```
    var ::=  Name | prefixexp `[´ exp `]´ | prefixexp `.´ Name 

    exp ::=  nil | false | true | Number | String | `...´ | function | 
         prefixexp | tableconstructor | exp binop exp | unop exp 

    prefixexp ::= var | functioncall | `(´ exp `)´
```

As you can see, it contains one recursive reference between var and prefixexp, which ends in an infinite loop. I think this is a case of left recursion, although indirect, because if you inline the definition of var, prefixexp ends like this:

```
    prefixexp ::= Name | prefixexp `[´ exp `]´ | prefixexp `.´ Name  | functioncall | `(´ exp `)´
```

I'm not sure if this grammar is supposed to be directly implementable (despite the lack of operator precedence) or if it will require some transformation first.

Comment: No, this grammar is not implementation-ready - it still contains glaring ambiguities such as the lack of operator precedence or associativity as you have pointed out; it is merely specific enough to precisely define what is a valid Lua program and what isn't.

Comment: It is a "BNF for a human" type of grammar :-)

Comment: I put this portion of the grammar in a BNF playground and it is able to parse it, and tree sitter seems to be fine with this kind of recursion too. How are they handling this?